« frères de cirque » : sens; Molloy, Samuel Beckett
Tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett

Car mes testicules à moi, ballottant à mi-cuisse au bout d’un maigre cordon, il n’y avait plus rien à en tirer, à telle enseigne que je n’avais plus envie d’en tirer quelque chose,
mais j’avais plutôt envie de les voir disparaître, ces témoins à charge à décharge de ma longue mise en accusation. Car ils m’accusaient de les avoir couillonnés, ils m’en congratulaient aussi, du fond de leur sacoche crevée, le droit plus bas que le gauche, ou
inversement, je ne sais plus, frères de cirque.

J'aurais tendance à croire que par l'image « frère de cirque » on dit « choses ou personnes qui se trouvent toujours ensemble ».
Je ne trouve cette expression nulle part. Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait confirmer ma supposition ou fournir la bonne définition ? S'agirait-il d'une métaphore morte ?

Tu ne va pas trouver de "définition" pour toutes les expressions qu'un auteur utilise, surtout un auteur comme Beckett.

@Frank Vous comprenez ou pas ? Si oui écrivez ce que vous comprenez.

J'aurais dit frères de comédie, ou peut-être, frères de cinéma. Mais cirque c'est mieux.

In English, Beckett uses circus clowns.

@Frank acrobates qui  ballottent.

Des jongleurs, ces deux frères, possiblement.

Tu dis: Je ne trouve cette expression nulle part. || Les écrivains cherchent à écrire des phrases en évitant les mornes clichés qui parsèment la langue comme des pauvres petits bourriques surchargées.

@Lambie Oui, mais les bons écrivains le font de sorte que ce qu'ils introduisent de nouveau a un sens ; dans le cas présent je peux tout aussi bien, ne sachant pas, supposer que ce qui est dit est que les deux choses sont plus ou moins les mêmes, deux acrobates élancés et musclés, avec des attitudes similaires, l'un presque une réplique de l'autre, frères de cirque. D'ailleurs je ne sais pas si c'est  vraiment nouveau ; je cherche aussi à savoir si ça n'a pas déjà été dit. I n'y a rien dans Google Books : si ce n'est pas de Beckett ça doit être très rare.

Non, user LPH, ce ne sont pas des acrobates élancés et musclés mais une métaphore pour une paire de gonades mâles qui pendouillent.

@jlliagre Une métaphore c'est quelque chose à la place d'une autre, d'un certain point de vue ; si une chose est les testicules quelle est l'autre chose placée sur le plan de l'analogie ? Les frères de cirque, deux artistes du cirque, mais rien de plus n'est dit ; alors il y beaucoup de possibilités.

@LPH Ton élancés et musclés est à côté de la plaque. L'extrait que tu as choisi n'est en rien flatteur pour les valseuses.

« élancés et musclés »  ce n'est pas du tout ce que est écrit:  "sacoche crevée" → ils sont plats" "il n’y avait plus rien à en tirer" → ils n'ont plus de jus,  À comparer avec la version anglaise : * For from such testicles as mine, dangling at mid-thigh at the end of a meagre cord, there was nothing more to be squeezed, not a drop. So that non che la speme il desiderio*. « si une chose est les testicules quelle est l'autre chose placée sur le plan de l'analogie » : les acrobates au bout de leur corde vs les testicules au bout de leur maigre cordon (ils pendent beaucoup...)

@LPH Les bons écrivains écrivent des choses que d'autres n'ont pas écrites avant eux, ils sont créateurs.  Victor Hugo était un maitre de la métaphore, dans ses romans, dans ses poèmes.  Prends  Les Misérables, Jean Valjean dans l'égout et ça se finit par « C'était la sombre étoile de la police qui se levait dans l'égout.  », remarquable, j'admire, simple en apparence et tellement parlant.  On ne reproduit pas la création d'un artiste, ce serait du plagiat, de l'imitation, pas de la création.

@None Au sujet de ce commentaire - Il ne faut pas confondre l'image que je donne de « deux frères » en prenant des acrobates (j'aurais pu prendre des dompteurs), et donc élancés et musclés tous les deux, avec la descriptions des piteux testicules du narrateur ; ça n'a rien à voir : l'analogie réside dans la relation de proximité qui coïncide avec des ressemblances pas dans les termes particuliers que prend la ressemblance. (1/2)

@None De plus, je suis loin de postuler une quelconque analogie entre le piteux ballotement du scrotum en suspension dans l'air et l'évolution élégante des acrobates dans l'air au dessus de la piste. (2/2)

@LPH Ce n'est pas le scrotum qui est en suspension, ce sont les testicules qui sont en suspension, le scrotum lui il est fixé, comme la corde serait fixé au plafond (ou autre)  C'est toi qui veut absolument en faire des acrobates à l'évolution élégante, ils le furent peut-être dans leur jeunesse mais là ce sont des acrobates finis, usés, délabrés, ils ont fait leur temps, ils sont vieux et ridés, ils n'ont plus la force de bouger, juste de se laisser pendre et être ballotés au bout de la corde

@None Je ne crois pas : puisque les testicules sont au fond du scrotum ils amènent la peau de cette poche vers le bas, et donc elle pend ; cette peau est en fait le scrotum. // Non, je le dis bien, ça aurait pu être des dompteurs, et on peut même en choisir plus  comme exemples. // Non, non, pas du tout pas d'analogie sur la ressemblance physique, seulement dans la relation de proximité de choses qui se ressemblent ou sont inséparables ; de quelle ressemblance il s'agit n'entre pas en ligne de compte.

@LPH C'est l'apparence qui est en jeu, pas l'anatomie ou la physiologie.

En fin de phrase comme ça, c'est rigolo. Presque vocatif.

@None Plusieurs ressemblances, quatre en fait : 1/ des testicules dans l'ensemble des testicules, 2/  des deux frères de cirques l'un à l'autre  3/ ressemblance  des testicules  à des acrobates, 4/ ressemblance du système 1 au syst. 2 (base de la met.)  ; les deux premières sont données (quasiment), mais il n'est pas question de la troisième, puisque on aurait pu choisir une paire de clown, une paire de jongleur, ou quelque autre paire d'artistes (« frères de cirque » n'est pas « acrobates »).  On a donc une ressemblance de deux systèmes de ressemblance ; c'est celle-là qui compte.

« Frères de cirque » n'est pas une expression toute faite. C'est une image,  Beckett file la métaphore du cirque.
Les testicules vont (en général) par deux et sont anatomiquement inséparables, ils sont frères, et frères de cirque tel des acrobates qui « ballottent » au bout d'une corde (« cordon » → le scrotum) quand ils font leur numéro.
Par ailleurs Beckett personnifie ses testicules qui s'en prennent à lui en le « mettant en accusation », mais il a de l'affection pour eux et les appelle « ces couillons » (affectueux ici). Ses testicules sont « témoins à charge à décharge », le mot testicule vient du latin testiculus qui vient lui-même de testis qui veut dire témoin, les testicules étant considérés dans l'antiquité comme les témoins de la virilité.

Le frère c'est le compagnon (TLF B.1.B) avec lequel on partage quelque chose. Certaines expressions se sont figées et on trouve parfois leur entrée dans un dictionnaire, comme frère de lait, frère de sang ou frères d'armes (et quelques autres) mais on peut très bien décliner le complément de nom à l'envie. Il y a  « mes frères de scène avec lesquels j'ai joué », « mon frère de chambre au pensionnat », « mes frères de galère avec lesquels je pointe à France Travail », « mon frère d'ennui avec lequel je m'assois au bord de la voie ferrée pour regarder passer les trains », « mes frères d'atelier avec lesquels je façonne des pièces à longueur de journées », « mes frères de club avec lesquels je fais du strip tous les soirs »...
Pour finir un exemple que je n'ai pas créé moi-même, mais pris sur un magazine culturel en ligne :

Trois vieux clowns, trois vieux frères de cirque qui ont partagé les mêmes pistes avant de se séparer de longues années, répondent à une annonce passée dans le journal « On demande vieux clown »


La corde en question me semble être le canal déférent plutôt que le scrotum.

@jlliagre Le canal spermatique il ne se voit pas à l’œil nu, il est à l'intérieur... le scrotum c'est la partie visible, le sac qui recouvre le tout, du moins c'est comme ça que je le vois !

Oui, je suis d'accord sur là dessus. Molloy décrit plus loin son scrotum comme des sacoches crevées d'où mon idée que ces cordons puissent être les canaux en question. Inutile cependant de disséquer plus avant notre héros, ces deux interprétations conviennent l'une comme l'autre à la bonne compréhension du texte.
